# Find the volume of the resulting solid. The region bounded by $y= e^{-x}$, y=0 and x=0 is revolved about x-axis.

Tags: calculus, volume, solid-of-revolution

Find the V of the  solid.

bounded by $y= e^{-x}, $y=0 and x=0 is rev about x-axis.

Comment: Have you tried setting up your integrals? Considering what method you will use? This isn't a website to do your homework

Answer (score 1):

Using the Disk/Ring Method we obtain: $V=\int A(x)dx$  where A(x) is the cross-sectional area of the solid. The area is $\pi(radius)^2$. The radius is $y=e^{-x}$. Consider where x is ranging from and solve the integral